# JasperReport CSV export has extra comma for stretched textfields

Tags: csv, jasper-reports

With Jasper Report 6.3.0, I am trying to export report to PDF & CSV format. With PDF format, it exports fine, I am facing an issue with CSV export.

Here is the snapshot of my report file.

[image]

Please note that there are some fields are extended to multiple fields.

Now when I export report to CSV, it shows as many commas as the fields are merged form other band. So for in stance in above scenario exported CSV has content like:

```
`12/19/2017 00:00 IST`,`All Segments`,`1`,`1 (100.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`
`Totals for instance`,,`1`,`1 (100.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`
`Totals`,,`5`,`5 (100.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`,`4 (80.00 %)`,`0 (0.00 %)`
`Jan 10, 2018 7:16:40 PM`,,,,`Page 1 of`,` 1`,,
```

I have set field enclosure to (`)

Any idea how can we nullify extra commas in CSV export?

Comment: `Any idea how can we nullify extra commas in CSV export?` - What do you mean? What is extra comma?

Comment: `'Jan 10, 2018 7:16:40 PM',,,,'Page 1 of',' 1'` , here after datetime field, there are extra commas. Jasper Report Textfield `$P{currentFormatedDateTime}` is stretched to the width of three textfields. And so there are exactly 3 commas between page number. These extra 3 commas are not expected, instead it should looks like `'Jan 10, 2018 7:16:40 PM','Page 1 of',' 1'`

Comment: You can prepare valid *csv* file (each record has the same number of fields/values as others records at file) with help of any language your know (Java, Python, C....). JasperReports engine don't know what is a "right data", it read the string and extract data by the rules you told to it  (with help of fields). If the data are heterogeneous - it can raise exception

Comment: If I export this report in excel format, then it does looks good. As stretched textfield is yield as merged columns in excel. So want to check that is there any JasperReport property available which can consider stretched field as one field instead of 3 (in this case particularly)?

Comment: Try to set removing property page header and page footer at time of exporting to CSV. like <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.(uniqueValue)" value="pageHeader"/>. you can check other export propert.